# Upgraded to PHP 5.6, unable to make MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysqli

I upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 5.6 to take advantage of >2GB upload capability in 5.6.  In doing so, the following line `dies`:

```
$db = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($dbhost,  $dbuser, $dbpass))
    or die("The site database appears to be down.");
```

The logfile message is:

```
mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

What about upgrading to PHP 5.6 would cause this line to fail?

Comment: maybe `die( "Database error: " .  mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) )` will tell you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386567/changing-from-mysql-to-mysqli-code-error

Comment: By the way, that usage of $GLOBALS is evil :)

Comment: @Len, this code was converted years ago and works fine under PHP 5.3.  Checking into first comment now.

Comment: @Qual - agreed.  Legacy site involved and these MySQL calls need to be migrated to something modern.  Right now trying to get the site working and usable.

Comment: well, did you upgrade by chance mysql as well? then resetting the password on the mysql side should suffice.

Comment: Have a look at this article http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php and to Elitscripts2000's comment. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Actually, yes - MySQL was updated as well.  That makes the log error clearer now.  `The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`.

Comment: @acoder try to re-set the password for the MySQL user, maybe?

Comment: I reset pw using `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` - still getting same errors in log.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html

Comment: This solved the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1340538/721073

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved.  MySQL was updated at the same time as PHP.  The old version of MySQL used the old password style, which didn't work with the new version of PHP.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340538/721073) was to log into MySQL on the server and reset passwords from the old 16 character hashes to the new ~40 character hashes.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'someuser'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepassword');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once that was done the site is working OK again.