# what is $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli first time. I have a question, what is $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] ? Can you plz tell me. I am not getting any direct answer when googling

Comment: It's the same as `$___mysqli_ston` in the global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a custom global variable.

See. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 10):

MySQLConverter assumes that this global variable is set to equal your DB connection object; if the converter finds a mysql_connect it will (partially, but with a warning) convert your code into code that includes an assignment of $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]  to the result of the mysqli_connect function something like this:

```
$link=($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $pwd));
```

See also [Changing from mysql to mysqli code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386567/changing-from-mysql-to-mysqli-code-error)